# How to rounding up in oracle

Tags: oracle, rounding

I want to convert this value "2167.124" to "2167.13" using round function in oracle 11g. Problem is that it converts LIKE "2167.12"
But i need  "2167.13".

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: That's how rounding works. Do you always want to 'round up', regardless of the value of theremaining digits?

Comment: What are your rules for rounding?

Comment: Try looking t the CEIL (and the related FLOOR)  function in Oracle to, though you might need to convert to integer first. Or, you would add 0.005 to the source number and then ROUND. But what happens when you have "9.991", do you want that then to round to "10.00"?

Comment: Actually i am creating reports for bank. It always avoid for .01 loss. that's why i want to round it like above i mentioned. And i am facing issue after decimal values. So need to convert like i mentioned above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to convert given value 2167.12" to "2167.13" Please use this

select ceil(2167.124*100)/100 from dual;

Comment: Thanks it resolve my issue. But one confusion is there that, why you multiply value with 100 and again dividing 100 ??? thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Sam's example, multiplying by 100 effectively moves the decimal point two places to the right, so your value becomes 216712.4:

```
select 2167.124*100 as step1 from dual;

     STEP1
----------
  216712.4
```

You then call [`ceil`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions024.htm) on that, to find "the smallest integer that is greater than or equal to *n*":

```
select ceil(216712.4) as step2 from dual;

     STEP2
----------
    216713
```

Then dividing by 100 effectively moves the decimal point back the same two places to the left:

```
select 216713/100 as step3 from dual;

     STEP3
----------
   2167.13
```

Putting the three steps together into one statement gets:

```
select ceil(2167.124*100)/100 as result from dual;

    RESULT
----------
   2167.13
```